# How to get the month wise records in c#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

My Table  like this.

```
name       date          phonenumber
venky      25-06-2013     123123123
vasud      27-06-2013     2423727384
sdfds      14-06-2013     12312332132
```

If user want to see june month records then he pass 06 as input parameter how to write linq to sql query to get june  month records as output..

Comment: Are you concerned about the year as well? For example, if your table had records from 2012 & 2013 - would you want to return all records for June in both years?

Answer (score 4):

Well it sounds like you just want something like:

```
public IQueryable<Record> GetRecordsForMonth(int month)
{
    return new RecordContext().Where(record => record.Date.Month == month);
}
```

That's assuming your `date` field in the database is actually an appropriate `datetime` field or something similar. If it's not, then fix your schema.

Alternatively, for dates within a range, you could take two `DateTime` values in the method and filter that way:

```
public IQueryable<Record> GetRecordsForMonth(DateTime minDateInclusive.
                                             DateTime maxDateExclusive)
{
    return new RecordContext().Where(record => record.Date >= minDateInclusive
                                            && record.Date < maxDateExclusive);
}
```